# build a macine learning model, using Hidden Markov Model

Tags: machine-learning, python, hidden-markov-model

I have a task to predict student retention by modelling student behavior by observing observable states (such as interaction with log data that contain accessing lectures,discussion, problem and so on) using “hidden markov model”,I have data also some research papers related to my problem.But have not idea how to implement HMM on this type of task,Please can you refer any link related to this type of objective implemented with HMM,or anything through which I can get idea how and where to start.Thanx

Comment: Hi kadima, HMM isn't a method but it's a model of a system that for example is used as an assumption for *techniques* like Reinforcement Learning. Here is a suggestion that might help others help you get what you want: (1) Write down the objective: "Need to predict student retention ... " in one sentence. (2) Bullet point what data you do have e.g. "student scores - mark out of 100". (3) Add a sentence mentioning that the solution needs to have some link to HMMs.

Comment: thanks,I will try change my question - in the meantime -  I tried find any sample similiar to this problem - without success. have any ideas?